# Weird behaviour matching exact phrases with sphinx

Tags: php, search, sphinx, exact-match

I am using the sphinx search engine. I need it to search for exact words in a field. Generally it works fine, but there are some weird anomalies.

```
$this->sphinxclient->Query('@title "Alfa Romeo 159"~3', "indexads" );
```

I try this. If I correctly understand this searches the field title and the margin between the words cannot be bigger as 2. I user the extended syntax of Sphinx.

```
$this->sphinxclient->SetArrayResult(true);
$this->sphinxclient->SetMatchMode(SPH_MATCH_EXTENDED2);
$this->sphinxclient->SetSortMode (SPH_SORT_RELEVANCE);
if($category_id>0)
    $this->sphinxclient->SetFilter('category', array($category_id));
$this->sphinxclient->SetFilter('status', array(1));
$this->sphinxclient->SetLimits(0,50000);
$this->sphinxclient->setFieldWeights(array ("title"=>1000,"description"=>0));
```

This is the code that I use to setup the search. Let me just says the filter does absolutely not affect the results I want. I use the extended syntax, because SPH_MATCH_PHRASE doesnt not work the way it is described at all. The extended syntax in generally doesnt work so bad.
  But the search doesnt return all the results that should match this query. Has anyone else ever withnessed anomalies with the search engine or am I doing something wrong. It is weird because I have two fields that are almost the same but it returns just one.

Alfa Romeo, 159 SportWagon,  1.9 JTDM Distinctive

Alfa Romeo, 159, SW Progression 1.9JTDm

This our two values of the field title, I think both should match the Query yet only the first one does.

Also when I search for something like Audi A8 I always get strings like Audi A6, Audi A4 also returned.

Comment: Wonder if SetLimits(0,50000); is the problem. There is a implicit max_matches of 1000 so that will never get all results.

Comment: The default value is 1000, but one can be changed in sphinx.conf, anyway it is not the problem.

Comment: YEs, but if you change it in the config file you need to ALSO change it when you call setLimits.

Comment: I have changed it in both config file and in setLimits.

Comment: What are your 'index' settings? Perhaps something like min_word_len is set too high?

Comment: min_word_len is set to 1, so not a problem

Comment: What about the rest of your index settings? Help us avoid this silly guessing game.